# Getting 'ERROR in ./src/polyfills.ts' while running `ng build --prod`

Tags: angular

I have setup Angular 6 project. 
I am trying to run `ng build --prod` but I am getting below error

> Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es7/reflect' in 'c:\localpath'

I am getting this error Angular 6 CLI version.

Comment: I noticed that sometimes when you install some single package, via npm install some package, it deletes other packages. that is why you get, it was just working now type of situation. just make sure that the package is listed in your package.json and check node_modules.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you got this error because you are using `-aot` compiler.

What you need here is open the polyfill.ts and comment the `import 'core-js/es7/reflect'`.

```
/** Evergreen browsers require these. **/
// Used for reflect-metadata in JIT. If you use AOT (and only Angular decorators), you can remove.
//import 'core-js/es7/reflect';
```

Hope this will help

Answer (score 1):

You can change 'es7' to 'es' as mentioned [here](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/14542), for me this worked:

```
import 'core-js/es/reflect';
```

But then I got

```
Error: Can't resolve 'core-js/es/global'
```

Then I noticed the version of my core-js was different from the one in the project, so I installed the specific version of core-js needed:

```
npm install --save core-js@^2.5.0
```

Hope one of these will solve your problem.